# Who are Darryl, Jacki, Paul, and Diane?

Tags: synthpop, personnel

First, some background from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Teens):

> Silicon Teens were a British virtual electronic new wave pop group.
>   The project was the creation of Mute Records founder Daniel Miller,
>   with Frank Tovey acting as the band's fictional frontman.
>
> The "group" were publicised as a quartet with members named Darryl,
>   Jacki, Paul and Diane, but in reality these individuals did not exist
>   and for media interviews their parts were played by actors, with the
>   band's lead singer Darryl portrayed by musician Frank Tovey. Tovey
>   did not perform on any Silicon Teens recordings; All vocals were
>   actually provided by Daniel Miller.

Watching [this video for Silicon Teens' 'Sunflight'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWkwpsTFY8w) showing promo shots of the actors.  I believe the guy on the bottom left is [Darryl/Fad Gadget/Frank Tovey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fad_Gadget), anybody know who the rest are?

[image: Silicon Teens promo headshots]

Answer (score 2):

Comparing to the picture at http://www.pias.com/blog/daniel-miller-lifes-playlist/, the guy in the upper left appears to be Daniel Miler himself.  He has the same nose, chin, lips, and earlobes, anyway.

My thirty minutes of research hasn't found any more answers than that.